# Randomize Multiple ul tags by class name using only JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, random

I have multiple ul elements on my page and I need to add a class name to some and those with that class name need to randomize. I can do it by id but I can only have one id on a page so I can't do that.  I need a JavaScript solution without JQuery.  Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Here is what I used to randomize it by id (it only does one ul though):

```
var thisUL = document.getElementById("myID");
for (var i = thisUL .children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    thisUL.appendChild(thisUL.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
}

<ul id="myID">
   <li>random1a</li>
   <li>random1b</li>
   <li>random1c</li>
</ul>

<ul id="myID">
   <li>random2a</li>
   <li>random3b</li>
   <li>random4c</li>
</ul>

<ul id="myID">
   <li>random3a</li>
   <li>random3b</li>
   <li>random3c</li>
</ul>
```

Each li would need to stay within its own ul.

Comment: Use class instead of id. Elements id should be unique. Like, `<ul class="myClass">`. And then select them with document.getElementsByClassName("myClass").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use  [*class*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) attribute, then use [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) to target all the elements having the [*class*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class). Then iterate them with for loop and you have the rest of the functionality:

```js
var ulList = document.getElementsByClassName("myElement");
for (let j = 0; j < ulList.length; j++) {
  var thisUL = ulList[j];
  for (let i = thisUL.children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    thisUL.appendChild(thisUL.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="myElement">
   <li>random1a</li>
   <li>random1b</li>
   <li>random1c</li>
</ul>

<ul class="myElement">
   <li>random2a</li>
   <li>random3b</li>
   <li>random4c</li>
</ul>

<ul class="myElement">
   <li>random3a</li>
   <li>random3b</li>
   <li>random3c</li>
</ul>
```